# mso-line-height clipping images in outlook

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

I am building an html template for a client which will create a drag and drop builder in mailchimp.

I have used the `mso-line-height:exactly` attribute globally to control erratic line height applied by Outlook.

However - because of this, when the client inserts an image into the body text using the 'insert image' text editor, the images is clipped at the line height of the text - for example if the line height is 20px, the image only shows the bottom 20px.

The solution I have been provided through research is that I have to remove the mso-line-height attribute globally and only apply it in the html code when I really need it - though this is not something a client can maintain.

How can I remove this attribute on images only? I want the exactly rule to be in place until such time as an image is inserted at which point is it m removed.

I have tried

```
img {
    border:0 !important;
    outline:none !important;
    display:block !important;
    mso-line-height-rule:at-least !important;
    mso-height-source:userset !important;
}
```

And also setting a 'min-height:insert image height !important' manually in the code editor inside the mailchimp interface but nothing works.

At the moment it seems like you only have 2 options

1 - you have correct line height but clients can never insert images amongst the text (the have to be table cells pre-designed to have images in them)

OR

2 - you have incorrect line height and non-clipped images but the ability to insert them when you want.

Is there a solution to this that does not involve editing the html each time but can be handled in in the css?

here is my initial styling

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

```
 <!--[if gte mso 15]>
<xml>
<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
<o:AllowPNG/>
<o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
</xml>
<![endif]-->


<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>template</title>



<style type="text/css">
        body{
            margin:0 !important;
            padding:0 !important;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust:100% !important;
            -ms-text-size-adjust:100% !important;
            -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased !important;
        }
    /*
    @tab Button
    @section background-Colour
    */
        .button{
            /*@editable*/background-color:#e5e5e5 !important;
            /*@editable*/color:#000000 !important;
            height:43px !important;
            margin-right:0 !important;
            font-size:15px !important;
            padding:0 5px !important;
        }
    /*
    @tab Button_2
    @section background-Colour
    */
        .button_2{
            /*@editable*/background-color:#e5e5e5 !important;
            /*@editable*/color:#000000 !important;
            margin-right:0 !important;
            font-size:15px !important;
            padding:0 5px!important;
        }
        a{
            text-decoration:none !important;
            color:black !important;
        }
        span.red-2{
            color:#bc3434 !important;
        }

        span.white-force {
            color:#ffffff !important;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .white-force a {
            color:#ffffff !important;
            text-decoration: none;
        }


        img{
            border:0 !important;
            outline:none !important;
            display:block !important;
        }
        table{
            border-collapse:collapse;
            mso-table-lspace:0;
            mso-table-rspace:0;
        }
        td{
            border-collapse:collapse;
            mso-line-height-rule:exactly;
        }
        a,span{
            mso-line-height-rule:exactly;
        }
        .ExternalClass *{
            line-height:100%;
        }
        .white a{
            color:#ffffff;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .white1 a{
            color:#333333;
            text-decoration:none;
            background-color:#333333;
        }
        .white2 a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .black a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .black3 a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .black2 a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .red a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .grey a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .grey1 a{
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .applewhiltelink a{
            color:inherit !important;
            text-decoration:none !important;
        }
        .video img{
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
        }



        .mcnTextContent img{
            height:auto !important;
        }



    @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        table[class=wrapper]{
            width:100% !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        table[class=main_table]{
            width:100% !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        td[class=pad_side]{
            padding-left:14px !important;
            padding-right:14px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        td[class=hide],br[class=hide]{
            display:none !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        img[class=full_img]{
            width:100% !important;
            height:auto !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        td[class=text],td[class=black],td[class=black2],td[class=red],td[class=white],td[class=white1],td[class=white2],td[class=grey], td[class=white-force]{
            text-align:center !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        td[class=pad_bottom]{
            padding-bottom:30px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        td[class=pad_top],
        td[class=pad_top_split]{
            padding-top:30px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        td[class=fix_height]{
            height:30px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (min-width:481px) and (max-width:599px){
        td[class=video] img{
            width:100% !important;
            height:auto !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        table[class=wrapper]{
            width:100% !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        table[class=main_table]{
            width:100% !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=pad_side]{
            padding-left:14px !important;
            padding-right:14px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=hide],br[class=hide]{
            display:none !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        img[class=full_img]{
            width:100% !important;
            height:auto !important;
            max-width: none !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=text],td[class=black],td[class=black2],td[class=red],td[class=white],td[class=white1],td[class=white2],td[class=grey],td[class=white-force]{
            text-align:center !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=pad_bottom]{
            padding-bottom:30px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=pad_top],
        td[class=pad_top_split]{
            padding-top:30px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=fix_height]{
            height:30px !important;
        }

}   @media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=video] img{
            width:100% !important;
            height:auto !important;
        }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
        td[class=pad_top_split]{
            padding-top:0 !important;
        }
}</style></head>
```

*edit

Each block that contains text (but may not necessarily end up with an image in it, has the class .grey - I tried these options but to no avail

```
.grey img {
line-height: 100px (random but taller then the test image)!important;
}
```

And also

```
.grey img {
line-height:unset !important;
}
```

I just want any images inserted amongst text to ignore the surrounding line-height.

here is an example block

```
<table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper" mc:repeatable mc:variant="text block" style="table-layout:fixed;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" bgcolor="#000000">
          <table width="650" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper">
            <tr>
              <td width="50" align="center" class="hide"> </td>
              <td valign="top" class="pad_side">
                <table width="550" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="wrapper">
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="40" class="fix_height"> </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" style="font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:15px;line-height:25px;color:#000000;background-color:#000000;" mc:edit="lorem_ipsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque vitae interdum ligula. Pellentesque feugiat ligula ligula, in interdum dolor aliquet et.</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td valign="top" height="40" class="fix_height"> </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td width="50" align="center" class="hide"> </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: How about adding it to a class that is on an element that will always contain text?

Comment: What styles are you setting inline on the `img` element and it's parent `td`? Could you separate text and images into different `td` elements so you can remove any `line-height` from the `img` parent?

Comment: I can't set any inline styles on the image because the client (whom has no coding skills) will be adding the images on a needs basis in the same way anyone using the built in default MailChimp templates can add images amongst text. 

The issue doesn't happen with the MailChimp editor but seems to present itself with mine and I can't work out why.

Every box that contains text has a class of 'grey' so I tried:

.grey img {
line-height:100px !important;
}

but that does not work (100px is a random height but taller than the image I was testing it with).

Comment: I have added some more info to the original question

Comment: I'm trying my hardest to replicate your issue, but it seems to function as expected. Can you [take a look](https://repl.it/@AnonymousSB/SO53656567) and see if it's far off from how you've programmed it?

Comment: Hi there - the issue only presents itself in Outlook, making it difficult to replicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `mso-line-height-rule: at-least` on your images. It's essentially the opposite to `mso-line-height-rule: exactly`.

[This blog post](https://cm.engineering/fixing-bugs-with-outlook-specific-css-f4b8ae5be4f4) might offer some more insight.

In my own builds I add this Outlook conditional style block below my other embedded styles. Then on my inline styles, I avoid using mso-line-height rule and only set font-size/line-height as normal

```
  <!--[if mso]>
    <style>
      td,th,p,a,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
        mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
      }
    <style>
  <![endif]-->
```